# How to display text without truncation in <input> tag, which is created by a framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I am using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) and there is this form that has a auto-complete field, for which I am having [`md-autocomplete`](https://material.angularjs.org/HEAD/demo/autocomplete) which uses a

```
<input type = "text" />
```

internally to render the text field. I am having a problem with this.
Whenever the text is longer than the width of the field, I want it to wrap, so that it is not truncated, and shown in the next line.

But with `<input>` there is no way to style so that overflow text is displayed in the next line(I know textarea fits my requirement, but `md-autocomplete` uses `input`).

So the question is how can I display the text without the truncation. Any suggestions would do. Please help!

Answer (score 4):

From the Doc [link](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdAutocomplete):

- `md-search-text-change` expression is fired when user change the text
- `md-selected-item-change` expression is fired when user select an item

My suggestion is to have your `md-autocomplete` hidden via CSS and hook these expression to update a textarea which the user will see and interact.

Sorry no working code for now. But I could create a plunker if you want. I have built similar for ui-autocomplete. Two input one with `ng-model="data.uiModel` and `ng-model=data.actualModel"`

Comment: It is too much overhead, I thought of the approach, but the look and feel of the text area has to be inline with that of the native Angular material elements and it would only make things harder with the Angular material updates.

Comment: I agree. But for this specific requirement I can't muster any better solution. Especially since there is no way we can add line break inside input. You can ask for more time to implement your own directive that wraps the `md-autocomplete` directive, for cleaner manageable code. Good luck, have fun ;)

Comment: The associated bounty kinda make me wanna try and create that custom directive for you, but.. i don't know. Do you want me to?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible with input type="text", but as a work around you can use title attribute in input and have same content as value. for example

```
<input type="text" title="something that exceeds the width of the box" value="something that exceeds the width of the box">
```

this will make sure your content will be visible completely on hover.

Comment: Best simplest answer! Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with the input element to truncate texts but one another thing can be done to provide an textarea element and position it on top of the input field.

Something similar to this:

**HTML:** 
`<div class="container-text">
<input type="text" id="myText" />
</div>`

**Javascript**

```
(function(){if(document.querySelector('#myText')){
var elm = document.createElement('textarea');
elm.className = 'myTextArea';
document.querySelector('.container-text').appendChild(elm);
document.querySelector('#myText').addEventListener('keyup', textChangeUpdate)}
function textChangeUpdate(){
   document.querySelector('.myTextArea').value = document.querySelector('#myText').value;
   document.querySelector('.myTextArea').focus();
}}());
```

**CSS**

```
.container-text{
    position:relative;
}
.container-text input, .container-text textarea{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    height:40px;
    width:130px;
    z-index:99;
}
.container-text input{
   z-index:100;
    opacity:0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5ysfbo3a/

You need to modify CSS for bringing dimension and look and feel as per your website need.

Note: Ensure that dimension of both elements are same so that your can see md-autocomplete element appear underneath of visible textarea.

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Ashok

Comment: Dude we are taking about Angular directives. Go read and understand how Angular works and how Directives work before you post answers like these. I'm not gonna down-vote, but I ain't gonna up-vote it either!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a `textarea` and JavaScript by adding an event listener for changes to the text area.

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dm5ppjo0/).

Comment: Dude we are taking about Angular directives. Go read and understand how Angular works and how Directives work before you post answers like these. I'm not gonna down-vote, but I ain't gonna up-vote it either!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple directive I whipped up which uses the textarea trick.  You will need to make some changes to get this integrated into your app - but that shouldn't be difficult.

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20128/

And here's a code pen showing it integrated with the `md-autocomplete` control. **I didn't try to wire up the data to the controller or anything. That's on you.**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjBKWR

Important things to note about my implementation:

- The single-line text input remains a first class citizen and is the thing with which the user interacts and the item which holds the final value of user input.
- The textarea is just used for visual display to give the appearance of an expanding text field.
- Keyboard navigation still works, and your scope is still bound to your original text input.
- This isn't 100% drop-in ready - you will need to make sure your styles match and all that - that's on you. I've also kept the demo so you can see the textarea come forward while focus only. Before you launch, you will want to set your input's opacity to 0;

**And the code code:**

```
myApp.directive('autoExpandInput', function() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: 'true',
      template: '' +
        '<div>' +
            '<textarea rows="1" tabindex="-1"></textarea>' +
            '<input type="text" value="{{inputValue}}" />' +
        '</div>',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
          elem.find('input').bind('focus', function (ev) {
              ev.target.tabIndex = -1;
              ev.target.previousSibling.focus();
          });
          elem.find('textarea').bind('blur', function (ev) {
              setTimeout(function () {
                  ev.target.nextSibling.tabIndex = 0;
              });
          })[0].oninput = function (ev) {
            var textarea = ev.target;
            scope.$apply(function() {
              scope.inputValue = textarea.value;
            });

            textarea.style.height = "";
            // you may need to play around with the math here a little
            if (textarea.clientHeight < textarea.scrollHeight + 2) {
                textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 2 + "px";
                textarea.nextSibling.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 2 + "px";
            }
        }
      }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest means is to leave the input alone and just display the query above (or below) the input box. Above is better as the filter list by default displays under the input. Using this method *is* a compromise, but works. You could always make the input zero sized or hidden, with a control to focus the input box on search-text-region click.

```
    <md-input-container flex>
      <span class="md-longwinded-search">{{ctrl.searchText}}</span>
      <label>Label</label>
      <input type="text"/>
    </md-input-container>
```

CSS:

```
    .md-longwinded-search {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        word-wrap: normal;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```